# Shaking desktop and windows in Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, intel-graphics, 22.04

I installed Kubuntu 22.04 on my HP ProBook 640 G3. I see from time to time that on moving the mouse cursor or switching applications or working with the system menu that desktop shakes. I'm not sure what is the problem: video driver, X11, Plasma, or something else.

I'm pretty sure that this is a software problem, because when desktop starts shaking, just move the mouse pointer and the problem is gone.

I reproduced the issue under Peek GIF recorder, configured to record with 30 FPS. I saw the issue on my laptop, but in GIF there is no shaking. What does this indicate?

I recorded a video of this shaky desktop on my camera. I'm sorry about the low video quality because the camera was shaking too, but you can still see the window shaking back and forth.

[image: Strange shaking in some places of menu]

It can occur in any place in any application. I don't think that this is an issue with hardware or a device driver. I suspect that it's an issue with hover events. Moving the mouse cursor solves the problem.

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-27-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
Memory: 7,6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company HD Graphics 620
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 134, IOMMU     group 1
    Memory at 1ff0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 1fe0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: Have you been in system settings and searched desktop effects? You will find many settings for animations such as glide, slide, fade, magic lamp etc.

Comment: No, no, this is not desktop effects. Can't reproduce, can't figure out what happens when this arrives...

Comment: what do you mean by "shaking"?  I would not rule out some type of hardware or driver issue but without more details its hard to really determine what is really happening.

Comment: I recorded this shaking on camera, look the link in the question.

Comment: Are you using the intel GPU or the AMD? This looks like a graphic driver issue.

Comment: I'm using Intel GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Today arrived kernel updates. It was `5.15.0-40-generic`. I tried to reproduce the issue, and was unable to do it. Will look for a few days yet, but I guess that the issue was fixed in this kernel.